# How to put labels at 4 points of the day?

Tags: chart.js, axis

This question is two-fold (two ways to solve)

I want to make a chart that plots 24 hours worth of data, not starting at midnight, and with ticks (and associated grid) at the four cardinal points of the day.

I don't care if the x axis is 'time' or anything else, as long as it looks fine. I've seen a category chart with the labels arbitrarily shifted, but I can only reproduce this with one data point per label, and this needs multiple data points between the labels. If I label all the data points I don't know how to skip labels such that only "0:00', '6:00', '12:00', and '18:00' are visible.

It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

This is how far I've come:

```js
function generateData() {
  function randomNumber(min, max) {
return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  function randomPoint(date) {
return {
  t: date.valueOf(),
  y: randomNumber(0, 100)
};
  }

  var date = moment("2000-01-01T"+"08:30");
  var now = moment();
  var data = [];
  while (data.length <=48) {
data.push(randomPoint(date));
date = date.clone().add(30, 'minute')
  }
  return data;
}

var cfg = {
  data: {
datasets: [{
  label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  borderColor: 'red',
  data: generateData(),
  type: 'line',
  pointRadius: 0,
  fill: false,
  lineTension: 0,
  borderWidth: 2
}]
  },
  options: {
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      round: 'minute',
      unit: 'minute',
      stepSize: 360,
      displayFormats: {
        minute: 'kk:mm'
      }
    }
  }],
  yAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      drawBorder: false
    }
  }]
},
tooltips: {
  intersect: false,
  mode: 'index'
}
  }
};
var chart = new Chart('chart1', cfg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1" height="60"></canvas>
```

The problem here is that the first tick is at 08:30 not at 12:00.

I've tried to set the min value of the axis, but this either shifts part of the data out of view (`min: moment("2000-01-01T12:00")`), or creates a gap before the data starts (`min: moment("2000-01-01T06:00")`), both of which are unacceptable.

```js
function generateData() {
  function randomNumber(min, max) {
return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  function randomPoint(date) {
return {
  t: date.valueOf(),
  y: randomNumber(0, 100)
};
  }

  var date = moment("2000-01-01T"+"08:30");
  var now = moment();
  var data = [];
  while (data.length <=48) {
data.push(randomPoint(date));
date = date.clone().add(30, 'minute')
  }
  return data;
}

var cfg = {
  data: {
datasets: [{
  label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  borderColor: 'red',
  data: generateData(),
  type: 'line',
  pointRadius: 0,
  fill: false,
  lineTension: 0,
  borderWidth: 2
}]
  },
  options: {
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      round: 'minute',
      unit: 'minute',
      stepSize: 360,
      displayFormats: {
        minute: 'kk:mm'
      }
    },
    ticks: {
      min: moment("2000-01-01T06:00"),
    }
  }],
  yAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      drawBorder: false
    }
  }]
},
tooltips: {
  intersect: false,
  mode: 'index'
}
  }
};
var chart = new Chart('chart1', cfg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1" height="60"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some time, but I think I got the answer.

You can define the ticks with and display them with `options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.source = 'labels'`, but the hardest part was to get the next timestamp of 0:00, 6:00, 12:00 or 18:00. 
That's why the code for the first label is quite complex. If you want to know anything, just let me know and I can explain it.

Should work with any time you want.

Complete code [(same as JSBin with preview here)](https://jsbin.com/homohaliti/1/edit?js,output):

```
let data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderColor: 'red',
    type: 'line',
    pointRadius: 0,
    pointHoverRadius: 0,
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0,
    borderWidth: 2,
    data: []
  }]
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}

// temp variable for data.datasets[0].data
let datasetData = []

// Fill first dataset
datasetData[0] = {
  x: moment("2000-01-01T08:30"),
  y: randomNumber(0, 100)
}

// Fill remaining datasets
for (let i = 1; i < 48; i++) {
  datasetData[i] = {
    x: moment(datasetData[i-1].x).add(30, 'minutes'),
    y: randomNumber(0, 100)
  }
}

data.datasets[0].data = datasetData

// Fill first label
data.labels = [
  moment(datasetData[0].x).hour(moment(datasetData[0].x).hour() + (6 - moment(datasetData[0].x).hour() % 6) % 6).minutes(0)
]

// Fill remaining labels
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  data.labels.push(moment(data.labels[i-1]).add(6, 'hours'))
}

let options = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'hour',
        displayFormats: {
          hour: 'kk:mm'
        }
      },
      ticks: {
        source: 'labels'
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        drawBorder: false
      }
    }]
  },
  tooltips: {
    intersect: false,
    mode: 'index',
    callbacks: {
      title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return moment(tooltipItem[0].label).format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm')
      }
    }
  }
}

let chart = new Chart('chart1', {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

Comment: It works great. You can simplify the formula from `(6 - moment(datasetData[0].x).hour() % 6) % 6` to `(24 - moment(datasetData[0].x).hour()) % 6`. Any particular reason you chose to use `let` instead of `var`?

Comment: That was only the 2nd part of the formula optimized. I didn't notice the first part from which it's subtracted. With it included the whole formula simplifies to `Math.ceil(moment(datasetData[0].x).hour() / 6) * 6`

Comment: It was late. I knew you can optimize this line but couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks for doing the work. I just learned that you should use `let` instead of `var` for les errors, but you can work with the scope from `var` as well. I just don't use it `var`.